# How to assign a random int to a JButton

Tags: java, swing, int

Is there any way to assign random numbers to JButtons? I'm creating a game where the player must click the draw button to shuffle the numbers on the cards. I want the numbers to be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9.

[image: picture]

How do I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating random integers in a specific range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-specific-range)

Comment: What is your problem exactly? How to generate random numbers 1 to 9 or how you set the Button with the number?

Comment: I want to first generate the integers, then randomly assign them to a button giving them a random number for every draw.

Comment: then, put this aclaration in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Random r = new Random();
r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min
```

This will generate random numbers for you within bounds (inclusive).  So, your min is 1 and max is 9.

to set text on JButton there is a method available (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setText(java.lang.String))